# Induction Proof: Sum of Products of $3$ Consecutive Numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm still trying to learn induction. But stuck on the following question. It will be highly appreciated if someone can show me how to do it.

I need to prove the following using math induction.

$$1\cdot2\cdot3 + 2\cdot3\cdot4 + 3\cdot4\cdot5 + \cdots + n(n+1)(n+2)= \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{4}$$ 
for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$

Comment: Do you know the steps to an induction proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is true for the case $n=1$, since $1\times 2\times 3 = 6 = \frac{1\times 2 \times 3 \times 4}{4}$.

Now, suppose that the formula is true for $n$.  We have that 
$1\times 2 \times 3 + \cdots  + n(n+1)(n+2) + (n+1)(n+2)(n+3) \\= \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{4} + (n+1)(n+2)(n+3) \\
= \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{4}  + \frac{4(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{4}\\
= \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}{4}  $

So, since the $n+1$ case is true, the induction holds.

Answer (score 0):

There's typically three steps to every induction proof. Let's call the formula on the right side $p(n)$.

1) Show that the formula is valid for the first case. So find $p(1)$ and check that it matches the left side.

2) Assume that the formula is valid for some integer $k$ (as in $p(k)$ is true). Then you need to show that it also holds for $k+1$. So find $p(k+1)$ and simplify. You should end up with some result that's written in terms of $p(k)$.

3) Since you assume $p(k)$ is true then $p(k+1)$ must also be true by PMI.